# interface Interface<T> : T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

Let's say I have this structure of classes and interfaces:

```
interface IService {}
interface IEmailService : IService
{
    Task SendAsync(IMessage message);
}

class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    async Task SendAsync(IMessage message)
    {
        await ...
    }
}

interface ICircuitBreaker<TService> : IService where TService : IService
{
    TService Service { get; set; }
    Task<IResult> PerformAsync(Func<Task<Iresult>> func);
}

class EmailServiceCircuitBreaker : ICircuitBreaker<IEmailService>
{
    IEmailService Service { get; set; }

    public EmailServiceCircuitBreaker(IEmailService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IResult> PerformAsync(Func<Task<Iresult>> func)
    {
        try
        {
            func();
        }
        catch(Exception e){//Handle failure}
    }
}
```

So now I'd like to change `EmailServiceCircuitBreaker` to:

```
class EmailServiceCircuitBreaker : ICircuitBreaker<IEmailService>, IEmailService
```

so I can wrap every method from `IEmailService` and `Send(...)` will look like:

```
async Task<IResult> IEmailService.SendAsync(IMessage m)
    => await PerformAsync(async () => await Service.SendAsync(m));
```

And in controller I can use it as `IEmailService` even if this is `ICircuitBreaker<IEmailService>` without knowing that.

But, if any of my colleagues will implement `ICircuitBreaker<T>` I'd like to force his class to also implement `T`

Comment: The description seems a bit backwards but are you trying to describe a scenario similar to the one described in Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and Curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/)?

Comment: What exactly is the question? The part `interface IInterface<T> : IService where IService : T` is syntactically incorrect; the type constraints must be on the type parameters.

Comment: To my knowledge C# doesn't support this kind of constraint, if you wan't all your team members to follow a strict rule, u can use the features of Roslyn Compiler

Comment: @Codor yes, I know that it's incorrect

Comment: @VibeeshanRC can you provide some link about this topic?

Comment: @GeliPapon I hope you can do this using Code Analysis, It will show errors whenever the such a code pattern is found.

Comment: @VibeeshanRC Yeah, it looks good but maybe someone will have some other solution for that

Answer (score 3):

When you wan't to have a new language constraint, then you can throw custom errors while compilation

You can create a Code Analysis as below, use `DiagnosticAnalyzer`

https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/creating-your-first-code-analyzer/

Using `DiagnosticAnalyzer`, you can search for the pattern and throw exception

```
 context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);

        private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var node = (ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

            if (node != null && node.Type != null && node.Type is IdentifierNameSyntax)
            {
                var type = (IdentifierNameSyntax)node.Type;

                var symbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(type).Symbol;
                var isIService = IsInheritedFromIService(symbol);

                if (isIService )
                {
                   ... //Check you logic
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                }
            }
        }

    private static bool IsInheritedFromIService(ITypeSymbol symbol)
    {
        bool isIService = false;
        var lastParent = symbol;

        if (lastParent != null)
        {
            while (lastParent.BaseType != null)
            {
                if (lastParent.BaseType.Name == "IService")
                {
                    isIService = true;
                    lastParent = lastParent.BaseType;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastParent = lastParent.BaseType;
                }
            }
        }

        return isIService ;
    }
```